# How to update another class's method?

Tags: methods, constructor, arguments, private

There are two classes (class Home and class Away). Class Away has a method called update and  update method has some arguments(speech,writing,reading) whose values are assigned in class Home. And these values change dynamically´.
I have problems at calling this update method from class Home, could you please give me an example? Here is what i tried to do :

```
public class Away
{ 
    private void method1(String speech)
    {
        //.......definition of the method......
    }

    private void method2(String writing)
    {
        //.....definition of the method......
    }

    private void method3(String reading)
    {
        //......definition of the method......
    }

    public void update(String speech, String writing, String reading)
    {
        Away away_object = new Away(String speech, String writing, String reading);
        away_object.method2(speech);
        away_object.method3(writing);
        away_object.method4(reading);
    }
}
```

I tried to call this update method from Home class in the following but i have no clue how to change the arguments of this update method.Because these arguments have dynamic values inside the Home class.Should i create a constructor, or how can i update this "update()"method?

```
Away object2 = new Away(); 

object2.update(speech, writing, reading);
```

I am looking forward to hearing your replies and i need it urgently...Thank you so much in advance...

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're trying to do or what the issue is.  In your `Home` object's `Update` function you're successfully creating an instance of an `Away` object and calling functions on it.  Then that instance falls out of scope after the `update` function on `Home` is done.  Is that not the intent?

Comment: Wait, sorry... I thought the class being shown was `Home`.  It's `Away`.  Why is `Away` creating a new instance of its own type and calling it?  Why not just call the functions on the current instance?  What are you trying to accomplish here?  As a contrived example this is pretty difficult to follow.

Comment: Hi David, since i m kinda novice in Java, i thought i m supposed to create an instance of Away class to be able to call a private method belonging to this class from another method in the same class. My aim is creating a method( update) which includes the other methods of the same class and whenever there is a change in the other class(which is Home) the values must be updated.

Answer (score 1):

In your public Update function inside the Away class you appear to be instantiating another copy of the away class itself.

Change your function as so:

From this:

```
public void update(String speech, String writing, String reading)
{
    Away away_object = new Away(String speech, String writing, String reading);
    away_object.method2(speech);
    away_object.method3(writing);
    away_object.method4(reading);
}
```

To this:

```
public void update(String speech, String writing, String reading)
{
    method2(speech);
    method3(writing);
    method4(reading);
}
```

Comment: Hello rbruceporter, thank you for the reply.However my main problem is about passing the updates to class Away. Because speech,writing and reading variables are created and assgined dynamic values in class Home.The reason why i created update() method is including all the methods belonging to Away class into one method so that i can call this method from Home class and pass the values of speech,reading and writing to this method and since this method includes the other methods of class Away, it will be easy to update them.Have you got my point?Thanks alot for the reply and waiting for ur reply

Comment: And there is sth missing in what i m doing to call this update() method from Home class coz i always get an error.i mean this doesnt work  :  Away object2 = new Away(); 
         object2.update(speech, writing, reading);          Should i create a constructor or add some arguments, i have no idea what to do exactly

Comment: btw,  the following belongs to Home class:                            Away object2 = new Away(); 

object2.update(speech, writing, reading);

Comment: I guess I am unsure what you are asking. If you make the edits as suggested, and as David noted above, the Home class can successfully instantiate the Away class and call the update method with the desired results. I think you need to reword the question so we can better understand what you are asking.